# Prevent non-exists data insertion - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

assuming that customers table contains 20 customers from id 1 to 20.

Any idea to prevent user submitted customer_id = 21 in invoices table?

User may try to alter the customer_id from html form before submit.

Comment: Are you using validation for this?

Comment: Use validation in the server side.

Comment: Yep! Just tried using "exists" validation. Working great!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, use Laravel "exists" validation.